# Relative paths in WebStorm

Tags: ide, webstorm

I am using Gulp for my frontend development and I am want switch to WebStorm. I am need for relative paths, because there is two dirs: `src` and `dest` and I must typed paths to `dest` directory. In `.html` file by press `ctrl + space` path inserts ok, but there isn't need `../dest/...`, I am want only `../`. In `sass` or `css` file path inserts without `../`. Is this fixed?

Comment: to me, double `ctrl+space` inserts a correct relative path from current file to selected resource, in both .css and .html. Please share a sample project that can be used to recreate the issue

Comment: @lena, [project](https://pp.userapi.com/c841432/v841432122/78f93/mgYIKAe2REY.jpg).

Incorrect path: `<script src="../dest/js/main.min.js"></script>`,
correct path what I want: `<script src="../js/main.min.js"></script>`

Comment: is it a path from `src/index.html`? but there is no `js` folder in the project root, so `../js/main.min.js` is not a valid path

Comment: to make things clear: marking a folder as **Resource root** allows resolving absolute path relative to this root, like `/js/main.min.js` or `js/main.min.js`. But this doesn't affect relative paths starting with `./` or `../` - these urls are always resolved relative to current file.

Comment: @lena, great, `/js/path/file` helped me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For WebStorm User:

You can use Ctrl+Space to get the path auto-generated. Just enter

```
import {}  from "any_file_name"
```

then put the cursor on "any_file_name" and hit Ctrl+Space twice - you will get the correct relative file path.

```
import {}  from "../../directory2/any_file_name"
```